# Count top 10 inputs in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function on my site where people can vote on photos. Everytime someone click the vote-button my script adds a row in a table (mysql).

Each row looks like this: (Table name = likes)

id --------- userId --------- photoName --------- date

1 ----------- 21 -------------- 34234 ----------- 20100101

How do i find the top 10 photos that people has been voting on?
I tried "*SELECT TOP 10 photoName FROM likes*" but that didnt work...

Comment: @Haljan: You can up-vote answers that you like. Once your problem is solved, accept the best one.

Comment: @Peter - he wasn't asking a meta-question :)

Comment: @Yuval A: Sure :) Nothing wrong with up-voting / accepting though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as points,
  photoName
FROM likes
GROUP BY photoName
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use some `count` with a `group by` ; something like this should help :

```
select photoName, count(*) as nbLikes
from likes
group by photoName
order by count(*) desc
limit 0, 10
```

i.e. you `group by photoName`, and you count how many times each photo has been liked -- and `order by` that number in `desc` order, to get the most liked ; and, finally, you use `limit` to only fetch the 10 first lines.